# Server logging setting up for python server and flask app

Tags: python, flask, logging, flask-socketio

I am new to python development.
We are working for a storeview application created on flask and python is used for server implementation.

I have to prepare server logging configuration file for keeping logs realtime.
How to start and reference needed for coding
we are using Main.py for execution

Answer (score 0):

I think all u need to do is to add the following two lines in the main:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="<path to directory location>/<log file name>", level=logging.ERROR
)
```

Then you can add log from any file/s needed:

```
logging.error("some error mesage")
```

Note that log location and log level(debug/info/error) needs to be adjusted based on your requirement.

Comment: What if there are some request,commands,falults alerts will be also generated so I need pure filtered logs for every function executed

Comment: In project folder there are different files available like utils,app,config, entities.. I am confused is any new file needed for global logging configuration or in available config py I can add codes to sync and call for all functions

Comment: U just need to above snippet in your main....then from any python file u can log messages. Its totally upto you on where/when/what messages you want to write in the log